# upgrading from vista to Windows 7-uninstal itunes and reinstall, do I lose all music/videos?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Dell Inspiron 1545 and am going to upgrade from Windows vista to Windows 7. The Windows 7 assistant says I have to uninstall iTunes before the upgrade and then install again after the upgrade. My question is will I lose all my music? Is there a way to do this without losing it?

Comment: One rule to rule them all: Back up; back up; back up!

Comment: You shouldn't lose it at all. As Journeyman says, it's about the drivers, not the data. Your settings are stored in your user folder anyway, and those should carry forward. But back up your data first.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how itunes installs - itunes tends to install a bunch of ipod related device drivers that probably won't carry forward to windows 7. 'saving' your itunes files may be as simple as renaming the folder, and dragging it back into your 'add to itunes' folder once you're done, even if uninstalling itunes deletes it (which i doubt) happens. As Kronos said - back up! It never hurts to.

Of course if updating from vista to 7 reformats the drive, you WILL want to copy it over to an external drive.

Comment: I saved itunes on my new passport hard drive but since it's new I wasn't sure if I can use it after the upgrade to download all the music on it. I started backing up the songs on DVD's but after 3 hours there's still hours worth left to transfer. My daughter has thousands of songs!  Do you think that since I backed up the music on the passport that i'm wasting my time using the DVD's?

Comment: I'm quite certain it is.Just make sure its all there ;). Assuming they arn't encrypted (in which case you'll want to deauthorise then reauthorise the system), it should 'just work'.